# C++ templates, vector.size used in default parameter definitoin

Tags: c++, templates, parameters, default, definition

There is a structure TA

```
template <typename T>
struct TA
{
    typedef std::vector <T> Type;
};
```

and test() function having a default parameter of the type TA.

```
template <typename T>
void test ( typename TA<T>::Type a1, 
            typename TA<T>::Type a2 = typename TA<T>::Type(a1.size()) )
{}
```

Is it posssible to use a1.size() in default parameter a2 definition?

```
int main()
{
    TA <double> ::Type a1;
    test<double>(a1);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [C/C++ default argument set as a previous argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880866/c-c-default-argument-set-as-a-previous-argument)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is it posssible to use a1.size() in default parameter a2 definition?

No. It is forbidden by the Standard. You cannot use function parameter to set the default value of other parameter.

§8.3.6/9 (C++03) explicitly says,

> Default arguments are evaluated each
>   time the function is called. *The order
>   of evaluation of function arguments is
>   unspecified*. **Consequently, parameters
>   of a function shall not be used in
>   default argument expressions**, even if
>   they are not evaluated.

So the solution is: use overload:

```
template <typename T>
void test(typename TAs<T>::Type a)
{
    test(a, typename TA<T>::Type(a.size()));
}
```

Answer (score 5):

No. In general, a function argument can't be used outside the body of the function, and specifically can't be used in the default value of another parameter.

You could get the same effect by overloading:

```
template <typename T>
void test ( typename TAs<T>::Type a1, typename TA<T>::Type a2);

template <typename T>
void test ( typename TAs<T>::Type a1)
{
    test(a1, typename TA<T>::Type(a1.size()));
}
```