# Forward use of function parameter

Tags: c++, function, parameters

I have remembered now that I saw something like this in C:

```
void foo(int bar; char baz[bar]) { ... }
```

I don't remember its name or the valid syntax and I wonder if it's available in C++ too?

Comment: nope it is not possible.

Comment: I don't think that `;` is valid syntax

Comment: This is not valid C or C++ code

Comment: @tobi303 + NathanOliver  It wasn't mean to be valid syntax, I just remember something like it and something that have sth. to do with forward-declared parameters, I'm just asking if it's available in C++, which, as bolov said, is not.

Comment: `bar` in `char baz[bar]` does not really matter anyway.

Comment: is `;` (afer `int bar`) a typo? If yes correct it to `,`.

Comment: @PcAF it's not a typo, it's intended, I thought it's a syntax for somethign like forward-parameters.

Comment: @R.O.S.S ups then I will rollback my edit

Comment: Maybe you are talking of this kind of forward use: `template <typename T> auto f (T t, size_t k) -> decltype(t[k]) { }` or `int f (T a, size_t k, decltype(T[k]) b);`? In which case it is perfectly valid since c++11.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's not possible according to the standard, since you are dynamically passing the size of the array to the function, unless there is some special compiler extension that I'm missing.

What you can do is to specify it as a template argument and let the deduction do its work, eg:

```
template<size_t size>
void foo (char (&a)[size])
{
   for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
     cout << a[i] << endl;
}

int main()
{
    char a[] = {'a','b','c','d','e'};
    foo(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Or, since you are working with C++, use an `std::array` or `std::vector` and iterators.

Comment: Oh, I didn't even know that there are template functions too. Thanks, I'll accept your answer ASAP.

Answer (score 2):

For starters, `char baz[10]` when used as a parameter declares a pointer, not an array, so `10` is completely ignored. This is called array decay to pointer and it's an unfortunate inheritance from `C`.

Considering you weren't asking strictly about array size, and expanding your question to any use of a previous parameter, the case would be default arguments. E.g.

```
void foo(int a, int b = a);
```

And here the answer is again no, it is not valid.

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1880877/2805305 for standard justification.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is some *"Forward use of function parameter"* in C++, but not what you are talking about.

Since C++11, you can do stuff like this to deduce type of parameters (or return type) using previous parameter:

```
template <typename T>
auto get (T const& t, size_t i) -> decltype(t[i]) { }
```

Or:

```
template <typename T>
void set (T &t, size_t i, decltype(t[i]) const& v) { }
```

Maybe I am completely off, but since you did not remember exactly what you saw, I thought this might have been stuff like this.