# why can't default argument depend on non-default argument?

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider the following constructor:

```
class MyClass {
    MyClass(unsigned int dimension, std::vector vector=unitaryVector(dimension));
};
```

where `unitaryVector(d)` is a function that returns a random `std::vector` in d dimensions.

This gives the following compiler error:

```
error: default argument references parameter 'dimension'
    MyClass(unsigned int dimension, std::vector vector=unitaryVector(dimension));
```

Why isn't this idiom valid in C++11? It seems to be pretty obvious: if `vector` argument is provided, init `vector` as a copy of the argument, otherwise, call the function and init it as a copy of the return value. Why can't a compiler understand this?

Comment: Your feature request seems like a very reasonable thing to want, but, is it in the standard? If not, compiler authors aren't obligated to implement it.

Comment: You might use an std::optional<> with a default value of empty instead of an explicit default value. This has the advantage that default value won't be part of your ABI and thus patching will be easier.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The C++ standard forbids it.

[dcl.fct.default](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.default)

> [**9**](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.default#9) default argument is evaluated each time the function is called with
>   no argument for the corresponding parameter. A parameter shall not
>   appear as a potentially-evaluated expression in a default argument.
>   Parameters of a function declared before a default argument are in
>   scope and can hide namespace and class member names.
>
> *[ Example:*
>
> ```
> int a;
> int f(int a, int b = a);            // error: parameter a
>                                     // used as default argument
> typedef int I;
> int g(float I, int b = I(2));       // error: parameter I found
> int h(int a, int b = sizeof(a));    // OK, unevaluated operand
> ```
>
> *— end example ]*

Note that default arguments are *replaced* at the call site if not provided

[Intro.execution](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.execution) *(emphasis mine)*

> **11:** *[ Note:* The evaluation of a ***full-expression*** can include the evaluation of subexpressions that are **not lexically part of the
>   full-expression**. For example, subexpressions involved in evaluating
>   default arguments ([dcl.fct.default]) are considered to be **created
>   in the expression that calls the function,** not the expression that
>   defines the default argument.  *— end note ]*

---

You can simply overload the constructor and delegate it:

```
class MyClass {
    explicit MyClass(unsigned int dimension) 
        : MyClass(dimension, unitaryVector(dimension))  //delegation
    {  }
    MyClass(unsigned int dimension, std::vector vector);
};
```

*Footnote: Its a good thing to make single argument constructors `explicit`*

Answer (score 3):

One alternative is to use

```
class MyClass {
    MyClass(unsigned int dimension, std::vector const& vector) :
            dimension(dimension), vector(vector) {}

    MyClass(unsigned int dimension) :
            MyClass(dimension, unitaryVector(dimension)) {}
};
```

(this of course when you want to store `dimension` and `vector` in the class).

Answer (score 1):

Because the default argument must be complete in itself so that compiler can simply replace it if not provided by call. The (local) variable `dimension` isn't created yet and you are trying to use it, and hence the error. This would work, however:

```
int _def_dim=10;
class MyClass {
    MyClass(unsigned int dimension, std::vector vector=unitaryVector(_def_dim));
};
```

I am not sure what standard says, but for compiler implementation is would be tricky to handle such corner cases.

EDIT (for completeness), grabbed from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1880877/264325):

> Default arguments are evaluated each time the function is called. The
>   order of evaluation of function arguments is unspecified.
>   Consequently, parameters of a function shall not be used in default
>   argument expressions, even if they are not evaluated.