# Using a parameter's name inside its own default value - is it legal?

Tags: c++, parameters, language-lawyer, default-parameters

```
enum class E {
    One,
    Two
};

void foo(E value = decltype(value)::One) {
}
```

It can be compiled with Clang (3.9), but cannot be compiled with GCC 6.1: `value was not declared in this scope`.

What compiler is right?

Comment: Looks like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880866/c-c-default-argument-set-as-a-previous-argument) is the answer but I am not 100% sure.  Leaving it to others to decide if it should be closed as a dupe.

Comment: @NathanOliver That question is about accessing the parameter's value, which is not possible for a good reason (order of evaluation), but I'd expect that its name and type be subject to different rules since that reason does not affect them.

Comment: @Quentin That is why I did not vote to close.  The quote from the standard has *Consequently, parameters of a function shall not be used in default argument expressions, even if they are not evaluated.* and I am not sure if that applies here or not.

Comment: @NathanOliver `int h(int a, int b = sizeof(a));` is used in an example as an error, so I'd say this isn't allowed, after all.

Comment: @krzaq No, that's commented with "Ok"

Comment: @NathanOliver That is not the same. The Standard forbids use of values in potentially evaluated expression, but `decltype(value)` is not a potentially evaluated expression.

Comment: @Columbo interesting, it is commented with Ok in N4606, but error in 4140.

Comment: I wonder if this is a language change from C++14 to C++17 then.  Maybe it was a DR.  In C++14 it N3797 it shows using `sizeof(a)` as being illegal.

Answer (score 9):

According to [[basic.scope.pdecl]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope.pdecl#1):

> The point of declaration for a name is immediately after its complete
>   *declarator* (Clause 8) and **before its *initializer*** (if any), except as
>   noted below.

So the parameter is definitely declared at that point. How about using it in `decltype`? Wording was outdated and inadvertently disallowed it. See [core issue 2082](http://wg21.link/cwg2082):

> According to 8.3.6 [dcl.fct.default] paragraph 9,
>
> > A default argument is evaluated each time the function is called with
> >     no argument for the corresponding parameter. The order of evaluation
> >     of function arguments is unspecified. Consequently, parameters of a
> >     function shall not be used in a default argument, even if they are not
> >     evaluated. This prohibits use of parameters in unevaluated operands,
> >     e.g.,
>
> ```
> void foo(int a = decltype(a){});
> ```
>
> This wording predates the concept
>   of “unevaluated operands” (the phrase “not evaluated” refers to calls
>   to the function where an actual argument is supplied and thus the
>   default argument is not used, not to unevaluated operands) and should
>   not apply to such cases.

So the [quoted paragraph](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.default#9) was amended to read

> A parameter shall not appear as a potentially-evaluated expression in a default argument.

Since operands of `decltype` are unevaluated, this is fine now, and GCC is wrong.

Comment: This was introduced only in draft, but not in C++14. http://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue2082

Comment: @vladon Yeah, I found that, too, after krzaq's comment.

Comment: Is GCC really wrong or does it just need to update how it compiles on c++17/1z?  Looks like was forbidden in C++14 so you really cannot fault GCC for that.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, you can; core defect resolutions must be implemented promptly, because they concern actual inconsistencies in the language. Also, what point is there in simply postponing all defect resolutions until release of the new standard?