# Function default argument value depending on argument name in C++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, language-lawyer, function-declaration, default-arguments

If one defines a new variable in C++, then the name of the variable can be used in the initialization expression, for example:

```
int x = sizeof(x);
```

And what about default value of a function argument? Is it allowed there to reference the argument by its name? For example:

```
void f(int y = sizeof(y)) {}
```

This function is accepted in Clang, but rejected in GCC with the error:

```
'y' was not declared in this scope
```

Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/YsvYnhjTb

Which compiler is right here?

Comment: Dup of [Using a parameter's name inside its own default value - is it legal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40513156/using-a-parameters-name-inside-its-own-default-value-is-it-legal)

Comment: Thanks for the reference, it is indeed a very similar question. Although the answers in this one seem more detailed.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

According to the C++17 standard (11.3.6 Default arguments)

> 9 A default argument is evaluated each time the function is called
> with no argument for the corresponding parameter. **A parameter shall
> not appear as a potentially-evaluated expression in a default
> argument.** Parameters of a function declared before a default
> argument are in scope and can hide namespace and class member name

It provides the following example:

```
int h(int a, int b = sizeof(a)); // OK, unevaluated operand
```

So, this function declaration

```
void f(int y = sizeof(y)) {}
```

is correct because, in this expression `sizeof(y)`, `y` is not an evaluated operand, based on C++17 8.3.3 Sizeof:

> 1 The sizeof operator yields the number of bytes in the object
> representation of its operand. **The operand is either an expression,
> which is an unevaluated operand** (Clause 8), or a parenthesized
> type-id.

and C++17 6.3.2 Point of declaration:

> 1 The point of declaration for a name is immediately after its
> complete declarator (Clause 11) and before its initializer (if any),
> except as noted below.

Comment: But then how do you explain the error given by gcc? Or is it a bug in gcc?

Comment: @KshitijJoshi It is a bug of the compiler.

Answer (score 9):

The code does not appear ill-formed, so Clang is alright.

> **[basic.scope.pdecl]**
>
> [1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.scope.pdecl#1) The point of declaration for a name is immediately after its complete declarator ([dcl.decl]) and before its initializer (if any), except as noted below.

This is the notorious passage that is under discussion. I bring it here just to mention that "except as noted below" doesn't include any mention of default arguments. So `y` is declared right before `= sizeof(y)`.

The other relevant paragraph is

> **[dcl.fct.default]**
>
> [9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.fct.default#9) A default argument is evaluated each time the function is called with no argument for the corresponding parameter. A parameter shall not appear as a potentially-evaluated expression in a default argument. Parameters of a function declared before a default argument are in scope and can hide namespace and class member names.

`sizeof(y)` is not potentially evaluated, so this is also fine.

Seeing as the first paragraph makes `y` available as a name, and it's used in a way that is not illegal, must be some quirk of GCC that rejects the code.

Though personally, I don't see it as a great loss. This is not the most practical bit of code.

Comment: Note that in C++11, there is a different formulation: _"parameters of a function shall not be used in a default argument, even if they are not evaluated"_. Link: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.fct.default#9.

Comment: @DanielLangr - Interesting. May be a left over in g++'s frontend. It does accept the standard's examples, though.

Comment: I think they should have just removed the restriction, and let the compiler order the defaulted arguments as needed for potentially-evaluated use of other arguments. Would have simplified use at least.