# Default argument doesn't work in msvc but works in gcc

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, default-value

I have learnt that function parameters can have default arguments. So I wrote up the below shown program that compiles with some compilers but not with other. I want to know why is this so. That is, what is the right compiler.

```
void f(int i, int j = decltype(i){})
{

}
int main()
{
  f(1);
}
```

[live test](https://godbolt.org/z/8dxEx1oxd)

I expected all compilers to agree.

```
example.cpp
<source>(1): error C2587: 'i': illegal use of local variable as default parameter
<source>(1): note: see declaration of 'i'
<source>(4): error C2660: 'f': function does not take 1 arguments
<source>(1): note: see declaration of 'f'
<source>(4): note: while trying to match the argument list '(int)'
Compiler returned: 2
```

Comment: Besides for experimenting, what you've written is totally useless. You know the type `i` and `j`, there's no need for `decltype` here. Just do `int j = {}` and it should work everywhere. And no matter the types of the arguments.

Comment: Order of arguments is Unspecified.

Comment: `decltype` is used to infer the type from an expression and in your example `j` is already `int` so what is the point in inferring the datatype of `i`? you could have written:

`decltype(i) j = decltype(i){}`; But again, the type of `i` is known so it is redundant to do so. This may come in handy if the type of `i` is a complicated type.

Comment: Dup of [Using a parameter's name inside its own default value - is it legal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40513156/using-a-parameters-name-inside-its-own-default-value-is-it-legal)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [CWG2082](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2082.html) and the program is **well-formed**. We have from [Default arguments documentation](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.fct.default#9):

> A default argument is evaluated each time the function is called with no argument for the corresponding parameter. A **parameter shall not appear as a potentially-evaluated expression in a default argument**. Parameters of a function declared before a default argument are in scope and can hide namespace and class member names.
>
> ```
> int h(int a, int b = sizeof(a));
> ```

(emphasis mine)

This means that the given program is well-formed since `i` in `decltype(i)` is unevaluated. So gcc and clang are correct in accepting the program.

---

Here is the msvc bug:

[VC++: local variable cannot be used in default arguments](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/vc-local-variable-cannot-be-used-in-default-argume/114320)

Comment: Interestingly OP's code compiles with `/std:c++20` on MSVC, but this example does not. Regarding CWG 2082, I could only find this [MSVC bug report](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/vc-local-variable-cannot-be-used-in-default-argume/114320), which was closed without fixing.

Comment: @Rane Yeah, definitely a msvc's bug.

Comment: @Rane Also compiles with `/permissive-`. That very likely means this is intended non-conforming behavior in non-conformance-mode.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug of the Microsoft compiler. As in this expression `decltype(i)` the parameter `i` is not evaluated then it may be used in this expression.